# Page losing resources in Spring MVC when changing URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've made a webview using Spring MVC (I'm quite new to Spring), and most of it is ok, but when I change page URL from `mydomain.com/admin/` to `mydomain.com/admin` my resource mapping crashes. I expected that Spring will understand both forms of URL, but I was wrong about it.

Here's the dispatcher servlet resource mapping with all experimental parts

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/admin/**" location="/resources/theme/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/admin**" location="/resources/theme/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="**/dist/**" location="/resources/theme/dist/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="**/bootstrap/**" location="/resources/theme/bootstrap/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="**/plugins/**" location="/resources/theme/plugins/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

The view itself

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<jsp:include page="partials/head.jsp"/>
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <jsp:include page="partials/header.jsp"/>
  <jsp:include page="partials/leftmenu.jsp"/>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">

    <!-- Content itself goes here -->


  </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <jsp:include page="partials/footer.jsp"/>
  <jsp:include page="partials/csidebar.jsp"/>

</div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<jsp:include page="partials/scripts.jsp"/>

</body>
</html>
```

partial

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- FontAwesome 4.3.0 -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Ionicons 2.0.0 -->
  <link href="dist /css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link href="plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Morris chart -->
  <link href="plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- jvectormap -->
  <link href="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
  <link href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well they are different URLs...  and you have different mappings for them. With what does it crash, post the code from your view.

Comment: There's no code. Just a webpage with no styles and js. A fragment of debug log is `14-Jul-2015 11:30:24.798 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-18] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
`. Others are the same

Comment: As requested post your view not the log and add it to your question not as a comment. Also add your web.xml or whatever way you use to register your `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Also `**/dist/**` wouldn't match why not simply use `/dist/**` instead? Looks like you are making your mappings to complex.

Comment: I tried both `**/dist/**` and `/dist/**`. Not working.

Comment: The problem is your URLs, use absolute URLs not relative as you currently have. Use the spring URL tag for this.

Comment: I look for a way to reach resources without chaging the template urls. The only trouble is that everything works perfectly when I request `mydomain.com/admin/` but crashes when I use `mydomain.com/admin`. this `/` fails everything

Comment: Because you are using relative urls and to absolute urls. That is the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the trouble.
I used

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/dist/**" location="/resources/theme/dist/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/resources/theme/bootstrap/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/plugins/**" location="/resources/theme/plugins/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

instead of

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/admin/**" location="/resources/theme/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/admin**" location="/resources/theme/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="**/dist/**" location="/resources/theme/dist/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="**/bootstrap/**" location="/resources/theme/bootstrap/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="**/plugins/**" location="/resources/theme/plugins/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

The mistake was operating page related URLs. As I tried to catch requests to my resource folder from wherever everything works nice